# Show Menu options vertically in Android

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to show menu options vertically means: one menu option is on the upper of two menu options that means there are three menu options two of them are at the bottom and last one is stays on the upper of rest.

Please help me regarding this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to invent your own "menu". You do not have control over the placement and sizing of menu choices in an options menu.

I encourage you to simply use the options menu as it is, to fit your users' expectations.